# npm install --save react-scroll-to-bottom not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, import

when I try to install React-scroll-to-bottom using the command npm i --save react-scroll-to-bottom I get an error that looks like this:
[image]

My Package.json looks like this:
[image]

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, react-scroll-to-bottom is not supported with react 17.0.1 so I changed my react version to 16.0.1

Answer (score 0):

run `npm install --save react@^16.0.0 react-dom@^16.0.0`